# material-ui multi avatars in listItems

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to create listItems in material-ui with more than 1 avatar (or better, more than 2, since you can put one on the left and one on the right, even if I don't know why you would do that)

Or more in general, is it possible to customize the content that goes inside the listItem or are we limited to the available attributes that are specified in the documentation (primaryText, secondaryText, etc?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can use the 'children' attribute on the ListItem component to pass custom content. I am not sure whether it is a good way to handle my case, but it seems to work fine.